# How can I discriminate between file and folder in DriveApp using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I know a folder actually is a file with a special mimeType `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` in Google Drive.
But documentation about DriveApp Folder class doesn't contain a method getMimeType() like DriveApp File class does.

How can find out in a function if an argument of that function refers to a folder or to a (normal) file?

```
function displayResults(fileOrFolder)
{
  var id   = fileOrFolder.getId();
  var name =  fileOrFolder.getName();

  var mimeType = fileOrFolder.getMimeType();  // works if file; error if folder

  if (fileOrFolder == <Class File>)
  {
     <do something>
  }
  else if (fileOrFolder == <Class Folder>)
  {
     <do something else>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look if the method exists. If obj.getMimeType===undefined its a folder.

or, to make it more robust in case the api changes (adds the method to folders), use
`if (obj.getMimeType===undefined || obj.getMimeType.toLowerCase() =="application/vnd.google-apps.folder")`

Comment: never too careful ;) +1 for exhaustivity .

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work. Actually using getMimeType() was what I tried myself (see code in my answer)

Comment: nop, its not getMimeType(), its getMimeType. See the code, copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you say that Zig's answer does not work... All the tests I made were positive.

example of how I tested it (test ID are shared publicly and so should work for anybody):

```
function test(){
  var item = DriveApp.getFileById('0B3qSFd3iikE3MS0yMzU4YjQ4NC04NjQxLTQyYmEtYTExNC1lMWVhNTZiMjlhMmI');
  testDriveFolders(item);
  var item = DriveApp.getFileById('1fXxLHuDlySZ6rOQjTsZdUl6rnw14sa17Q0ZTZ0HoGk1jbuHX-eLq1dyf');
  testDriveFolders(item);
}

function testDriveFolders(obj){
  try{var mimeType = obj.getMimeType()}catch(e){mimeType = 'folder'};
  var name =  obj.getName();
  if (mimeType =="application/vnd.google-apps.folder" || mimeType == 'folder'){
    Logger.log(name+' is a folder');
  }else{
        Logger.log(name+' is of the type '+mimeType);
  }
}
```

Comment: No need for try/catch. In the code i provided i do Not call getMymeType(), i do obj.getMimeType===undefined which is very different. Is checking for existance of the function, not calling it (until later)

Comment: Yes indeed, I used it making a mix of the other post and yours because I started by testing his code (that was said "not working").  In the end both methods seems useable...

Comment: yes sorry I wasnt complaining about this approach, just pointing out why hes try at it wasnt working. try/catch in general is not the best idea because methods could throw genuine error exceptions and not just language exceptions about the method not existing.

Answer (score 0):

Get the file object associated to the ID. getMimeType() will work:

```
var mt = DriveApp.getFileByID(fileOrFolder.getId()).getMimeType();
if (mt == MimeType.FOLDER) {
  // it's a folder
} else {
  // it's a file.
}
```