# How to get Spreadsheeets/Documents owned by a particular user using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

In the situation if someone leaves a company, to transfer all the files (Spreadsheets, Documents, Sites, Slides etc) they own to someone else, is there any method or a function to list the files using apps script ?

For instance, if I am trying to list all Spreadsheets owned by person with email "xyz@google.com", may be like SpreadsheetApp.getSheetsOwnedBy("xyz@google.com"). I tried finding something like this but could not find any. Could anyone please share your knowledge on this if you have idea.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Deleting and posting back doesn't change the fact that the question is duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65306744/

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, you can transfer files from a user with the [Data Transfer API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/reference/rest/v1/transfers)

You need to be an admin to do so.

There is a nice [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65227750/how-to-execute-data-transfer-api) showing you in detail on how to perform the transfer in Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this below code could satisfy my requirement, I will leave this piece of code here just in case someone has similar requirement.

`

```
function transferOwnership() {
 

 var count = 0;  //to keep track of total no. of files
 var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"me" in owners'); //can give emailAddres in place of "me"
// var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "untitled"'); //gives list of files containing the files that incluede "untitled" in file title
 
while (files.hasNext()) {
 var file = files.next();
 count++;
 Logger.log(file.getName());
 Logger.log(file.getMimeType());  //to know under which mime type category the file falls under
 //file.setOwner("xyz@google.com"); //automatically original owner becomes editor
 //file.addEditor("xyz@google.com");
}
 Logger.log("total count: " + count);
 
}`
```

Someone posted similar post here which is very useful:

[Looping through multiple google spreadsheets with google scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537807/looping-through-multiple-google-spreadsheets-with-google-scripts)